# Create a list of all cells next to a certain value

Tags: excel

I have tried multiple searches and multiple formulas but can't seem to get this one right.
I am close, but I don't get the results I am looking for.

Basicly, I want to create two separate sheets.
The first sheet will consist of 4x4 squares containing information about ID, Price, Rent, Pros/Cons etc, this is using the area A2:U125. 
The second sheet is supposed to be a table that sums some of the information in the first sheet.

I basicly want to create a table from the sheet with the 4x4 boxes and I need to extract price, rent, ID and a few other variables.

The area with the 4x4 boxes consists of two columns of descriptions and two columns of values. So for example I have the description ID in A2, F2, K2 and then again in A8, F8, K8 and their respective values in the column to the right of them, B2, G2, etc.

What I want to do is to but them in a table like this:

Column A is all values next to cells saying "ID"
Column B is all values next to cells saying "price"
and so on...

I have tried using the INDEX, VLOOKUP and the IF functions but I can't seem to get it right. The closest I got was using:

=IF(AND(LEN(B2>0);A2="ID");B2;NA)
But I am not able to rewrite this in a way the covers the entire area I want to find values from and them all to one list. I simply had to make four different lists using this, one for each column with ID and respective values.
I don't know if this would be easier to do in VBA, but I don't have experience enough to have any clue about how I would do that.

I would be extremely thankful for any help. I have no one to ask at work and I am basicly learning excel from scratch.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [so]!   It would be helpful if you include examples of what you have and what you "need to have".  Visual clues tend to make more sense (and get more help) than a lengthy written description.  (See also: "[mcve]" and as well as "[ask]" for more hints.)

Answer (score 0):

That formula doesn't work, try this:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(B2>0),A2="ID"),B2,"NA")
```

Now click on the bottom right of the cell and drag it down to drag down the formula.

Right above the first cell with the formula, add a header, this will allow you to filter out the "NA" cells. You should be left with a complete list of all the values for "ID".

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with an intermediate step.

To simplify I performed everything on a single sheet - otherwise the queries would be unreadable.

Based on your description I've built this sample (it will be my starting point):

[image: initial sheet]

1) Extract data from each group of columns (A and B, F and G, K and L) into 3 groups but with header at the top. So you have ID, Price, Rent, Pros/Cons in a single row. As an intermediate step we will build 3 groups like that. I started in column W.

[image]

Some `#N/A`s - we will clean that in next step.

But first a description of this step. The W to Z column deals with values from A and B. AB to AE with F and G, AG to AJ with K and L.

Each cell is a `VLOOKUP`:

W2 = `=VLOOKUP("ID",A2:D6,2)`
X2 = `=VLOOKUP("Price",A2:D6,2)`
Y2 = `=VLOOKUP("Rent",A2:D6,2)`
Z2 = `=VLOOKUP("Pros/Cons",A2:D6,2)`

Now, the important part, When you populate these values for the next row. The lookup box **should** move by one row:

W3 = `=VLOOKUP("ID",A3:D7,2)`
X3 = `=VLOOKUP("Price",A3:D7,2)`
Y3 = `=VLOOKUP("Rent",A3:D7,2)`
Z3 = `=VLOOKUP("Pros/Cons",A3:D7,2)`

This way we are moving our lookup and only search for single occurance of "ID", "Price", and so on. If you run it on a full range you will end up with duplicates.

The same for further rows. You will achieve the result if you simply drag the cells down, or copy paste them down.

For the AB to AE group, and for AG to AJ you will need to adjust the lookup ranges to F:G and K:L respectively.

Now, the final step - cleanup.

In my sample the result is in AL to AO columns:

[image]

Here we will operate on first 3 rows and then will copy the results down.

Basically Results row 1 needs to refer W to Z row 1.
Results row 2 needs to refer AB to AE row 1.
Results row 3 needs to refer AG to AJ row 1.

Then you take first 3 rows of the results and copy them down. This will produce the following outcome:
Result row 4 will refer W to Z row 2.
Result row 5 will refer AB to AE row 2.
Result row 6 will refer AG to AJ row 2.

Then you copy the results farther down till you cover all the values.

Once you have the results done this way you can copy paste them to a different sheet or you can start your calculations on a different sheet.

Comment: Thanks the reply and the time and effort put in to it!
I am not really getting it to work as intended even though I'm following all steps you mentioned.  

  First of all I had to add another row to my boxes, which means they are 5 rows and 4 columns, however this shouldn't impact the formula if I understand it correctly.    

  However, when I do the VLOOKUP step, I end up getting the result for rent in two columns and NA in the area columns. Like this
https://imgur.com/urJ8GCu  

This is how the work area looks atm.
https://imgur.com/a/Rg5zPTp

Comment: You get the incorrect result as in your picture b/c - I suspect - when you copy the formula to the right the range of the columns also changes - but it shouldn't. So if you are in column D and your referencing A and B, after copykng it from E to D you still should reference A and B.

Comment: I checked and the formulas are written similar to yours. Except I have another range. I tried playing around with it a bit. Seeing as you are using A2:D6 (going one row below the actual text) I used C2:D7 to mimic this. However, this gives now gives me the correct numbers for ID, Rooms and Area.
However, if I used C2:D7 for "Price" is returns "ID", but if I instead use C2:D8, price returns price. Same goes for rent, C2:D7 returns N/A but C2:D10 returns the correct value.  

Any ideas?

Comment: While I am at it, I'm not doing that well on cleaning up all the duplicates (as in your first example). What formula/function are you using to clean this up? Right now I have the "correct" results in row 2, 9, 16 and so on.